# How to use Self Join to separate data with no relationships in RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am building a prototype for a inventory system for a clothing store. This app manages item markdowns, original price,Markdown price, colour, availability.

the app imports an excel file and maps the columns and the rows of the excel to a model.

there are 6 columns in total, both male and female clothes have the same attributes. But I'd like to separate the item by gender.

I can upload all female data, then upload all male data, but I am not sure how to handle it on the import end. Since they both have the same attributes, I feel like it is a waste to simply make 2 separate models for this.

I looked into self joins, but these items have absolutely no relationship with each other.

How would I handle this?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Why not have a column that specifies male or female (or unisex)?

Comment: because that seems incredible inefficient, since I'd have to write hundreds of rows with either 'Male' or 'Female'

instead of having a cluster of the row mapped as category 'male' or 'female', then when I try to sort, I don't have to query row by row to categorize them.

Comment: You said separate item by gender, not attributes. Note this is what sti oies, it had a column indicating which class to instantiate-no difference in doing it yourself, just handled by rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're thinking of doing is a Single Table Inheritance, STI. You could have a parent model, ItemMarkdown, or whatever, and that would also be the table in the database. You'd have a field "type" which would be either "MaleItemMarkdown" or "FemaleItemMarkdown" and then Rails would know that, when it instantiates those items that it should instantiate them as that class. You'd have to create those classes, of course, and they would inherit from ItemMarkdown.

Comment: yes! thank you! I thought I read something about that in Rails, but I had forgotten what it was. This is it.